# Write across pages

Tags: double-sided

In a doublesided document, how can I force latex to allow a table to cross from an even page to the adyacent odd page?

I am trying to do this both with a large diagram (xypic), a table and then a figure.

Thanks,
D

Comment: The Longtable package (and many other) allow you, to create tables, that are longer than one page and hence have to be split up across several pages.  To my knowledge, there is no method, to let the table begin on even or odd  pages, as this is driven by LaTeX normal float algorithms.  I don't know, if something similar exists for figures. :-(

Comment: do you mean that the table or figure is long, and can break vertically, or is wide, and you want the left half on the even page, and the right half on the odd page?  the first should be doable (and depends on where the table/figure is placed in the input stream), but for the second, i know of no "automatic" or package-driven method.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The figure is too wide for one pagewidth, and to high to use a landscape. However, since I am printing as a book, it would nice to have the reader open the page and see it across a even and odd pages.

Comment: @DG -- you should add that description to your question, which can easily be misinterpreted otherwise.

Comment: Actually a great idea for a new package. Maybe `tabularx` could be extended somehow to achieve this?

Comment: @DG Not too elegant, but simple and it work: two half tables in two top floats.

Comment: @Fran And what if the first one ends up on an odd page?

Comment: @MichaelPalmer No. Sadly not.

Comment: For the table, see the `longtable` solution discussed at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141749/split-longtable-over-even-and-odd-pages-2 or in the linked earlier question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97369/how-to-make-a-long-table-split-on-even-odd-pages. Probably it should be easier with a `tabular`, I'm not sure.

Comment: @cfr I would simply move the floats in the final version, but I suppose that a a macro using `\FloatBarrier`,  `\ifoddpage` and `\afterpage` should work also for this purpose.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93808/column-wise-break-of-extra-wide-tables