# Is There a Way to Automatically Break up Overly Wide Tables in LaTeX

Tags: longtable

My application automatically generates code to be processed by pdflatex based on tabular data it records. I can't make a lot of assumptions about the data. How many columns there will be and what sort of data it contains depends on a number of factors. A lot of text that can't be broken up, such as numerical serial numbers, can be found in the table. There are often enough rows to span multiple pages (sometimes hundreds or even thousands of pages - I dearly hope my customers aren't printing those reports).

In some cases, the data ends up being too wide to be printed and I get these kinds of warnings:

`Overfull \hbox (392.01555pt too wide) in alignment at lines 7--20`

Here's an example of code that generates this warning:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{*{10}{l}}
    Avg. Strength &
    Date &
    Error No. &
    Lot No. &
    Max. Strength &
    Serial Number &
    Speed &
    Test Grip Position &
    Unit &
    personnel
\\
\hline
\endhead
    1.12 &
    27 Jun 2013 22:11:15 &
    0 &
    0000000000 &
    1.78 &
    00000000000000000000 &
    11.8in./min. &
    0.4in. &
    lbf &
    ADMINIST
\\
    1.17 &
    27 Jun 2013 22:13:01 &
    51 &
    0000000000 &
    1.44 &
    00000000000000000000 &
    11.8in./min. &
    0.4in. &
    lbf &
    ADMINIST
\\
    1.51 &
    27 Jun 2013 22:15:03 &
    0 &
    0000000000 &
    2.18 &
    00000000000000000000 &
    11.8in./min. &
    0.4in. &
    lbf &
    ADMINIST
\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I like the judgements that latex packages tend to make and trust them over my own micro-managing of cell widths, etc. What I would like is to accept longtable's judgement as to what the cell widths ought to be, then break up the table so that it never runs over the end or resize it.

In short, is there a way out of the box I can do this or some code someone else figured out who faced this same problem? If not, is it feasible to write a package that does this without having to get into arcane innards of tex? I'm not a tex person and I'd rather start with longtable's functionality, but with breaking up (or otherwise compensating for excessive width) added in.

**Update**

Here's pseudo-code for what I'm trying to do. I'm willing to (and would actually prefer to) do everything on my application's side, except I have no way of knowing in my code what the widths are.

```
max_width = page.get_line_width()
for table in get_tables():
  width = 0
  sub_table = []
  for col in table.cols():
    if width + col.width() > max_width: # Not handling single col being too wide edge case
      print_table(sub_table)
      sub_table.clear()
      width = 0
    width += col.width()
    sub_table.add(col)
  if sub_table not empty:
    print_table(sub_table)
```

Comment: And note that if I break it up, I'd enumerate the rows for cross-referencing of course.

Comment: Welcome! Basically, I think the answer is: (1) there is no out-of-the-box solution, (2) there is no code somebody else has developed to solve this problem, and (3) it is not feasible to write a package without getting into the arcane innards. Moreover, (4) it is not feasible to write such a package by getting into the arcane innards either. You can manage something for a particular case very often e.g. [David's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97369/how-to-make-a-long-table-split-on-even-odd-pages). But you are looking for a fundamentally different output routine from TeX's.

Comment: However, if you have data in, say, `.csv` format, you could write a script to pre-process it, splitting rows and adding the relevant numbers for cross-referencing. This should be pretty straightforward on a Unix-ish platform (GNU/Linux, OS X, maybe Cygwin etc.) and presumably there's some way on Windows, although I would have no idea about that. This will be orders of magnitude easier than having TeX do it. (Yes, TeX is Turing complete so technically, I assume you could do it. But in real time... I suspect not so much.)

Comment: So from your first post, I gather that tex simply isn't suitable for automatically generated code? I get that feeling when I see answers for other questions asked by people trying to do so.

Comment: Your second response doesn't make sense, especially given your first response. I'm writing code that generates lyx. I have all the data on hand and can easily manipulate it to generate the tex I want _if I know how many columns will fit_. The whole problem is that I don't know ahead of time. I only know by printing and then looking at the output (and shaking my head).

Comment: It does make sense: TeX isn't suitable for splitting the table. But if you pre-process the data to split the table, then you can feed it to TeX. The problem is less generating code programmatically (TeX is bad for that, but your data is already generated). But you can't split a table horizontally between pages because of the way TeX processes input as a stream of tokens. But it is easy to split a `.csv` table using an external tool and then feed 2 (or 3 or...) tables to TeX. Probably you can estimate the number of columns by e.g. counting characters. Pre-process - don't try to split in TeX.

Comment: Naturally, I'd rather write as much code as possible in c++ (what my application is written in) and as little as possible, preferably none, in tex. The whole reason I ask this question here is because "counting characters" is hacky and unreliable. To put it in python-flavored pseudo-code, I'd like to:

Comment: Okay I added pseudo-code in my original question. I hope that clears things up. If there's a way to ask tex for the widths, then I can do it on my application's side. If not, then it has to be done in tex somehow (or in lua if luatex gives me access to this information).

Comment: Maybe let your TeX generating code iterate generating smaller documents with only that table, and run it through TeX to see what happens?

Comment: What would "see what happens" constitute? Can I make it spit out the widths to stdout or something?

Comment: Well, you could check for warnings about overfull boxes. Specifically, overfull horizontal boxes. If the table is the only thing in the document, you'd know you needed fewer columns and could start another iteration with one fewer. Of course, in some cases, it would likely be better to have multi-line cells rather than splitting a column out and I don't suppose there's a nice way of testing that programmatically. You might look at the way something like `tabularx` or `longtable` sets things up. That's within TeX but the iteration idea is similar.

Comment: Yeah, that would work although it could take forever, especially when the row count gets astronomical. If there was a way to \showoutput the actual widths, I can do it only two passes. I am looking at the longtable.sty code to see if there's a token or register or something I can just print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically my code now adds

```
\typeout{width=\the\textwidth}
```

to the tex file, runs latex in draft mode first (re-running as needed), then captures textwidth using regex on the output. It also captures the name of the .aux file and loads that. **The generated aux file contains the dimensions made by longtable**. Why didn't you tex experts tell me that? I discovered that almost on accident and I don't know tex! Literally that's the only piece of information I needed if it's really not possible to split up in tex itself.

I hope this isn't the *best* answer because it's a pretty terrible answer. I have to run latex for each table to get the widths longtable came up with, and that could be hundreds of tables. This is on top of many other problems with trying to ship a stripped-down tex distribution with software.

Comment: Well, if you'd pinged somebody after asking about the widths, somebody would have said. But you talked to nobody. When only you and I commented, I got pinged. Once pst commented, nobody gets pinged unless you ask.